# Which part of a country is called "western interior"?

Tags: word-meaning

> In the late 1230s the Swedish nobleman Birger Jarl led a punitive expedition to Finland’s **western interior**, more precisely Tavastland,
> where the local inhabitants had allied themselves with Novgorod.
> (bolds by me)
>
> A history of Finland by Henrik Meinander

Can someone explain precisely which part of any country is considered as western interior? I want to translate this text to my language and I am confused.

You can see in the map that Tavastland is located almost in the center relative to eastern and western borders of Finland. So what is its connection with "west"?

Answer (score 1):

Let’s use the United states as an example. Nevada and Colorado are in the western interior of the United States. Montana is not because it is on the border between the U.S. and Canada. Oregon is not because it is  one of the westernmost states. West Virginia is not because it is in the eastern part of the U.S.

Comment: But "western interior" is not a term that is in everyday use in the United States is it? You have the mid-west, the inter-mountain west, and the west coast. These expressions tend to be specific to the countries concerned and "western interior" is probably a direct translation from Swedish or Finnish. In Britain we talk about the West Midlands (Warwickshire, Birmingham, Staffs etc) and the East Midlands (Leicestershire, Derbyshire, Nottinghamshire).

Comment: @WS2 The point is not whether "western interior" is a **common** descriptor for some part of the U.S. The point in whether it is a **geographically clear** descriptor for any country. Quite frankly, I have no clue at all about what different parts of Finland were called in medieval times. But I do know that "western interior" means that it was close to, but not bordering on, Sweden and was far from the city of Novgorod. It creates a clear picture of the geography that "Tavastland" does not.

Comment: @ WS2 By the way, you have not provided a map of medieval Finland . You are aware that Russia absorbed a chunk of eastern Finland around 1944. So, Tavastland may not have been central to what was considered Finland before the late twentieth century. But if you believe that "central" better describes the geography of Tavastland relative to the geography of Finland in the late 13th century, by all means use "central." In terms of its historical boundaries, it looks more western than eastern to me.

Comment: It is Western in comparison to vast area over which Finno-Ugaric tribes roamed, following the reindeer, which stretched well into Siberia.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tavastia_(historical_province)